# UnityEngine.Transform does not contain a definition for local scale?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to having moving platforms that my game Object can jump onto and move along with it. I can have the object stay on the platform but not fall through but when the game Object is on the moving platform it gets stretched out or shrunked. I thought I could fix this if I updated the local scale in the code but Unity says it doesn't have the definition for local scale which doesn't make since.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class trigger : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
{ 
    other.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    //other.transform.localScale (1, 1, 1);
} 
void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) 
{ 
    other.transform.parent = null; 
    //other.transform.localScale (1, 1, 1);
}
}
```

Just in case you need to know I have a cube object without a mesh at the same position and size as the platform that acts as a trigger. Just in case you want to see it here's my script to move the platforms.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class movingPlatforms : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3 pointB;
public GameObject pig;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    var pointA = transform.position;
    while (true) {
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0f));
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0f));
    }
}

IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform thisTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
{
    var i= 0.0f;
    var rate= 1.0f/time;
    while (i < 1.0f) {
        i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
        yield return null; 
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "PIG")
    {
        //this.transform.position = pig.transform.position;
        //pig.transform.position += this.transform.position;
    }
}

void triggerOnStay(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.tag == "PIG")
    {
        collider.transform.parent = transform.parent;
    }
}
}
```

Is there a way to get the locale scale to be defined in my script, or if not that a better way to have my game Object move with the platform, any help would be appreciated.

update: i changed the locale scale updates to other.transform.localScale = Vector3.one; It workfs fine for the On trigger Exit but for on trigger Enter i get this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNnAk.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Transform has a definition for [Transform.localScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) the problem is how are you trying to access that element, there is no method called localScale() you have to use the variable localScale (internally is a getter/setter).

---

Instead of

```
other.transform.localScale(1, 1, 1);
```

try

```
other.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
```

---

Internal implementation:

[image: internal implementation of localScale getter/setter]

Comment: It seems to work for the on trigger exit but when I apply it in the on triggerEnter even though it says he scale the same in the inspector the view get messed up.

Comment: do you have the log? Can you try what happens if you comment the prev line, i mean (other.transform.parent = null; ) ?

Comment: what do you mean by do I have the log?

Comment: My concern is if you are having an exception (you can check the console output) if not probably the problem is in the logic of the code instead of be a unity problem.

Comment: I'm not getting a exception so something is wrong with the logic then. I think its the camera that's messing up since the view returns to normal when the game object gets off the platform.